# programmatically define the name of a variable that's at the left side of the assignment operator

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, stringr

I want to programmatically (loop or map) define the name of a variable, something like

```
for (i in 1:10) {

 str_c("variable_", i) <- i

}

# or

map(1:10, ~{
 str_c("variable_", .x) <- .x
 }
)
```

so that, in this case, I end up with 10 vars in my environment, namely: variable_1, variable_2, ..., variable_10.

but I get the following error

"
Error in str_c("variable_", i) <- 1 :
target of assignment expands to non-language object
"

Is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For such cases specifically is `assign()` which takes a string as its first argument which gets converted into a variable.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  assign(paste0("variable_", i), i)
}
```

This is the shortest way to do it in R.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
for(i in 1:10){
     .GlobalEnv[[paste0("variable_", i)]] <- i
}
```